# How to set the current page programmatically in angular kendo grid?

Tags: angular, telerik, kendo-grid

I am stuck with angular telerik kendo grid. The question is simple: how can I set the current page of the grid in code? 
There are search filters outside the grid. When the user changes the filter and the grid it is not the first page, the data will not be shown because there might not be enough rows and the grid stays on page 2. When the user clicks the search button, the grid should reset to the first page. In code I have a reference to GridComponent. There is no method showpage() or something similar. I found answers for kendo grid but not for angular kendo grid. Tnx
P.s.: i use custom binding https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/automatic-operations/

Comment: Are you using client or server side paging?

Comment: I am using server side paging, only 10 rows are displayed at a time and sent to the client. Maybe I have a solution, to set the this.grid.skip =0; and then somehow to trigger a new search from server. But I assume this is not the right way.